# Only one activity in Back Stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have 5 activities: A, B, C, D and E.

I can start all activities from each of them, but I want that Back Stack only save the last activity.

For example: A->B->C->D. If I am in D, I can go back to C, but now, in C, when I push back button I want to only can go to the main activity (A).

Is it posible?
Thanks!

Comment: If you can go from D to C then wouldn't you have 2 `Activities` in back stack, A&C? What if go from B to C, can you go back to B? What if you are in E, you only want to go back to D then A?

Comment: Is this the constant sequence i.e. A->B->C->D and your intention is to skip just B. Or you are maintaining a count or level for the activities that you want only 2 activities in the back stack. i.e. first activity and the last activity before the current activity?

Answer (score 1):

When transitioning from B -> C, call the finish() method on Activity B.  This will prevent B from being placed on the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the back stack once you are in C and navigate to A.

A to B.B to C. C to D.

Back D to C

In C you can use the below.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    onBackPressed();

    }

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }

public void onBackPressed() {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(C.this, A.class)
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//clear top of stack.
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
return;
    }
```

Comment: But this won't allow the OP to go from D to C

Comment: Ok, this would work but I'm curious what the OP wants if the user is in E, hence my comment in the OP. But if this is the only situation they need then this would be the answer

Comment: if he is in E then he can come back to D by back pressing and then to c by another back press and then to A.

Comment: I understand what it will do with the example you have given, I was just trying to figure out if that is what the OP wanted. I took it as to only ever allow one back press before going back to A